# Как решить запрос SELECT?

Tags: php, select, sql

```
<? if($cmd=='newSave' ) 
     $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_FORM_TITLE; 
   else $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _EDIT_FORM_TITLE;

   if($p_strType == 'advert'){ 
     $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_ADVERT_FORM_TITLE; 
   } 
   $DBbrand_opt[0] = _PLEASE_SELECT; 

   if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля'){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 
     AND (vip = 2 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC"; 
   }else{ 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND (vip = 1 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC"; 
   }
?>
```

Comment: что то вообще ничего не понял

Comment: Да все просто. Смотри код. Может слишком подробно описал...

Два выпадающих списка. Сортировка по колонке vip. 

vip = 2 марка отражается в разделе Добавление нового автомобиля; vip = 1 марка отражается в разделе Продажа VIP автомобиля; vip = 0 марки нет ни там ни там; vip = 3 марка и там и там.

Вопрос редактирования. Выводит список:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND (vip = 2 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC";

а нужно чтобы выводил 

else $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND (vip = 1 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC";

Comment: @Serg107, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

`$arr['_form_title']` - для редактирования чему равно?- какие данные на сервер прилетают?

попробуй так переписать

```
If ($cmd == 'newSave')
{
    $strvip ="vip in (2,3)";
}
else
{
    $strvip ="vip in (1,3)";
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND ".$strvip." ORDER BY name ASC";
```

да и создания текста запроса добавь лучше в этом месте

```
if($cmd == 'newSave')
    $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_FORM_TITLE;
else
    $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _EDIT_FORM_TITLE;

if($p_strType == 'advert') {
    $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_ADVERT_FORM_TITLE;
}
```

Comment: Изначально был общий список на все. 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
Задача стала разделить на 2 списка - короткий вип и длинный все в куче...

разделили 

$DBbrand_opt[0] = _PLEASE_SELECT;
if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля') $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND (vip = 2 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC";
else $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_models WHERE parent_id = 0 AND status = 1 AND (vip = 1 OR vip = 3) ORDER BY name ASC";

Comment: ну так где формируется значение переменной $arr['_form_title']??

Comment: жесть...))))))

Comment: if($arr['_form_title'] == 'Добавление нового автомобиля' - не есть хорошее условие, могут тупо поменять наименование формы, поэтому я бы лучше от If ($cmd == 'newSave') шел бы

Comment: Что помогло, вместо _EDIT_FORM_TITLE тупо поставил _NEW_FORM_TITLE (получилось 2 _NEW_FORM_TITLE). Вроде списки выводит правильно, но Вместо редактирования пишет Добавление нового автомобиля...

if($cmd == 'newSave')
   $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_FORM_TITLE;
  else
   $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_FORM_TITLE;

        if($p_strType == 'advert'){
            $this->pageTitle = $form_name = _NEW_ADVERT_FORM_TITLE;
        }

Comment: *Спасибо Ale_x!*